# Get two kvm guests to iperf between each other

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, virtual-machine, kvm

I am having trouble getting two kvm guests to connect to each other and run iperf (one guest being the server and the other being the client).  They can ping each other fine.

More information: these two guests are running on the same machine.  I set a bridge with "brctl addbr br0" on the host machine

I run the guests with this command:

sudo kvm IMAGE1 -m 2G -net nic -net user -net nic -net tap,script=ifup,downscript=ifdown

The "ifup" is thus:

```
\#!/bin/sh

switch='br0'
/sbin/ifconfig $1 0.0.0.0 up
brctl addif ${switch} $1
```

The /etc/network/interfaces on each guest is thus:

```
\# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.1.10
hwaddress ether 52:54:00:12:35:56
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

the interfaces file is the same on the other guest save for a different ip for eth1 (192.168.1.14) and hardware address

I've added routes so that each guest pushes 192.168.1.x traffic out of eth1 and that the host routes 192.168.1.x traffic into br0

Also note, the Ip's of the guests are distinct from of the IP of the host machine (host machine IP: 10.0.1.130)

Pinging between the two guests works just fine, however, iperf does not work.

On the guest running the iperf server, the interesting thing is that it says it connects with 10.0.1.130 (local 192.168.1.14 port 5001 connected with 10.0.1.130 port 49072).

On the guest running the iperf client, it says "local 192.168.1.10 port 50779 connected with 192.168.1.14 port 5001."  It outputs something obviously wrong as its output after 10 seconds.

The guest running the server outputting some things periodically ("0.0-0.0 sec 0.00 Bytes 0.00 bits/sec")

Sometimes as well, the guest running the client won't connect, saying connection reset by peer.  Ping still works fine.

Any and all help will be appreciated beyond measure.

Comment: check iptables..and do this: iptables -F AND check with tcpdump whether packets are received at VMs. Share iperf command used.

Comment: Thanks for the interest.  This particular project has been put on the back-burner for the time being. I'll do what you suggest if I pick it back up again. Thanks.